# Under sink p trap unable to remove

Tags: plumbing

[image]

I'm trying to remove the p trap under the bathroom sink.

#4 is obvious to remove.

Unfortunately, I can't figure out which other connection to turn. I tried turning #3 in the same direction as I turned #4, but it wouldn't move at all.

Two questions:

- where to I turn other than #4 to loosen the p trap?
- I think my attempt to turn #3 has caused a leak at #1. Is it possible replace the pipe starting from #1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the parts are hand tied, no wrenches needed.

You P-trap is partially glued.

The 3 & 4 turn in opposite directions.

Remove/unscrew #4 and #3.

Pull down.

Be ready for some water in the P-trap.

Comment: OP is already ready—see the foil pan? :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove 4.

Loosen 3. Use a wrench below 3 to hold that part stable while loosening 3. 3 is oriented in the opposite direction that 4 is, so they do not loosen in the same direction (they both loosen counterclockwise, but the clock gets flipped...) If you have a wrench on 3 with the handle to the right, you push it into the screen to loosen. If you have wrench on 4 with the handle to the right, you pull it out of the screen to loosen.

Pull down.

If you have loosened 1 inadvertently, you may need to tighten it, or to disassemble and reassemble. You should not have to replace the parts unless you've done something egregious, but you might need fresh plumber's putty or silicone sealant as specified by the sink manufacturer.